# How to stream unknown amount of bytes to server using BackgroundUploader?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have a heavy IO/CPU conversion 'process', converting from filetype A to B. Currently I write this out to a StorageFile, then upload using BackgroundUploader, when the conversion is done.

However, I want to start streaming sooner, while the output file is still being generated. Furthermore, I don't necessarily even want to create the output StorageFile, but instead upload 'on the go'.

Note, I do NOT know the final size of the output file during conversion, it could be smaller or larger than the source.

First, I tried simply opening the sink output StorageFile while writing to it, and passed that stream to BackgroundUploader, but this results in a 'race condition', where the upload terminates when it reaches the end of the bytes written to the StorageFile (when it catches up to the conversion work).

Instead of streaming to the StorageFile, I can also write the output bytes to a buffer, say 2KiB for example. I would like to upload this buffer after the conversion writes to it.

```
//simplified code...
uint bytesRead = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[buff_sz];
bytesRead = converter.Read(buffer);
while(bytesRead > 0)
{
    // here I would like to 'upload' the data (maybe using BackgroundUploader? or some other API?)
    bytesRead = converter.Read(buffer);
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this without running into the same 'race condition' I did before. How do I keep the BackgroundUploader running until I am done putting new bytes into the buffer?

Note 1: The last iteration will be bytesRead < buff_sz, so I need to communicate that also somehow, so as not to upload garbage bytes at the end.

Note 2: The Conversion code is in a cross platform C++ shared library.

Thanks!

**Supplemental**

Based on Nate Diamond's suggestion I looked into IINputStream interface. Code below works, though possibly the worst performance version you could write, but enough to prove the concept.

Following wrapper code based on 'maxim pg' implementation from here.
[How can I implement IRandomAccessStream in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723354/how-can-i-implement-irandomaccessstream-in-c)

```
 public IAsyncOperationWithProgress<IBuffer, UInt32> ReadAsync(
    IBuffer buffer,// The buffer into which the asynchronous read operation places the bytes that are read. 
    uint count,// The number of bytes to read that is less than or equal to the Capacity value.
    InputStreamOptions options) // Specifies the type of the asynchronous read operation.
{
    if (buffer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");
    Func<CancellationToken, IProgress<uint>, Task<IBuffer>> taskProvider =
    (token, progress) => ReadBytesAsync(buffer, count, token, progress, options);
    return AsyncInfo.Run(taskProvider);
}

private Task<IBuffer> ReadBytesAsync(
    IBuffer buffer, 
    uint count, 
    CancellationToken token, 
    IProgress<uint> progress, 
    InputStreamOptions options)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<IBuffer> cts = new TaskCompletionSource<IBuffer>();
    try
    {
        var ignore = ThreadPool.RunAsync((handler) => {
            _buffer = new byte[count];
            uint bytesRead = _reader.Read(_buffer); // this triggers file conversion work
            buffer.Length = bytesRead; // this is important apparently, otherwise no data written!
            Stream stream = buffer.AsStream();
            stream.Write(_buffer, 0, (int)bytesRead);
            stream.Flush();
            cts.TrySetResult(buffer);
        });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        cts.SetException(e);
    }
    return cts.Task;
}
```

Comment: So, one thing that I notice is that IInputStream (what `BackgroundUploader.CreateUploadFromStreamAsync` accepts) is a simple interface. It has a single method that you have to override. What I'm thinking is that you could create your own `CustomInputStream` class which accepts input and continually allows reading until it is closed. [Others seam to have had success with similar concepts](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e29d15b9-b8d4-4e3c-994c-2be98c0922f4/how-to-stream-video-an-iinputstream-into-xaml?forum=winappswithcsharp).

Comment: Though, I'm not sure if that's really necessarily. Would you mind posting the code that you used to try it before but caused the race condition? Like, could you make a simple `InMemoryRandomAccessStream` without writing it to a file and use that? (It has a `GetInputStreamAt` method for this purpose).

Comment: thanks @NateDiamond, I took your advice on implementing the IInputStream interface. It wasn't totally straight forward, especially for TAP noob like me. I'll add the code I'm using to my question in case anyone ever cares. Please submit an answer and I'll vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the easiest way for you to do this will be to create a custom `IInputStream`. It's an interface with only one method, `ReadAsync`.

All you then have to do is create your `CustomInputStream` which continually allows input and returns from `ReadAsync` when it has enough content to fill the requested block. It also has a `Close` function which tells it it is done.

[Others have implemented something similar in `IRandomAccessStream` successfully](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e29d15b9-b8d4-4e3c-994c-2be98c0922f4/how-to-stream-video-an-iinputstream-into-xaml?forum=winappswithcsharp).

Comment: Thanks for good tip. It 'works' now, but the strange thing is BackgroundUploader::CreateUploadFromStreamAsync doesn't return until the conversion is done.

I assume this is because the upload needs to know the content size before hand, for the HTTP request header.

I probably still have a performance benefit not using a StorageFile as the intermediary, but obviously this is gonna blow memory up, as I could be uploading hundreds of megs!

Comment: It matters how the `BackgroundUploader` processes the stream for uploading. There's no reason that your custom stream can't remove what's already been sent to the uploader from memory. Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the Read method and seeing if it's being called repeatedly or only once? The other option you have is to split it up into chunks. You can then put a header at the front of each chunk which works as an index and have your server put them back together upon receiving them.

Comment: Yeah, definitely the issue looks like the BackgroundUploader wants the Content-Length header for the PUT method. Read keeps being called till I say zero bytes written, then it never calls again.
 Not sure if I can do chunk uploading using BackgroundUploader, might switch to System.Net.Http.HttpClient (which I use for the rest commands, and which doesn't use the UI like Windows Store HttpClient). However, I'm trying to upload to AWS S3... which doesn't allow chunks! Rackspace does, or maybe I'll upload to our own server first, and our server can upload to S3 since it now knows the size.

Comment: [According to this it should](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/11/amazon-s3-multipart-upload.html), though it was intended for large files.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was referring to Transfer-Encoding: chunked though.

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1109#14

While I could be dealing with files that are hundreds of megs, typically they will be 'hopefully' just a few megs, or even less than 1MB. The link you sent has a 5MB limit, but certainly might be something that we use in some cases. Thanks again for the help.