# How analyze or read data real time from stream- Windows universal 10

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have `InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream`, where I'm capturing audio data, ([implemention](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Audio-Recorder-In-Windows-2d80c2fd))

```
await capture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(AudioEncodingQuality.Auto), stream);" .
```

Is it possible to analyze stream in real time? I want to set thershold and read data that are higher than threshold, etc. So, It's such a detector, which detects specified amplitudes of sounds. For example, it could count peaks or something.

I would be pleased too with implemention, where i just check input from jack plug in a specified time perioids. Then I would get data points too.

**=========================================================================**

**Edit:** Now I have the solution for this.
Basic implemention of recorder follows this [Windows 10 Universal Windows Platform – Audio Recorder](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20uwp%20record%20audio) . I have just changed a device id to correct one.

```
            MediaCaptureInitializationSettings settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
            {
                StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio
            };
            settings.AudioProcessing = Windows.Media.AudioProcessing.Raw;
            settings.AudioDeviceId = myDeviceId;
```

Audio settings:

```
       profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.Auto);
       profile.Audio.SampleRate = (uint) samplesPerSecond; // Samples per second
       profile.Audio.BitsPerSample = (uint) bitsPerSample; // bits per sample
       profile.Audio.ChannelCount = (uint) channels; // channels
       // Capture to stream 
       await capture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(profile, buffer);
```

Running task for reading while recording

```
        // Copy the capturing stream
        readingStream = buffer.CloneStream().AsStreamForRead();

        // Set delay for fetching data
        double period = 1 /((double) samplesPerSecond);
        int delay = (int) Math.Ceiling(period * 1000); // Convert to milliseconds

        // Set size for byte array
        int bitsPerSecond = samplesPerSecond * bitsPerSample;
        int bitsPerPeriod = (int) Math.Floor(period * bitsPerSecond);
        int bytesPerPeriod = (int) bitsPerPeriod / 2;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesPerPeriod];

        // Seems to work better this way
        delay = 2 * delay;

        while (readingStream.CanRead)
        {
            if (!Recording)
            {
                break;
            }

            // Reading frequency
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            // Read available bytes
            await readingStream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            // Get Avarage value of decoded bytes
            amplitude = Math.Abs(Decode(bytes).Average());

            // Update UI (These are my own methods to convert data to more human friendly format)
            GeneralUtil.setAmplitudeBarValue(amplitude);
            if (amplitude>treshold)
            {
                GeneralUtil.visualizePulse();
            }
        }
```

Delay time and reading doesn't fit perfectly atm, but it need only little adjustments for variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution isn’t good: burns battery, eats RAM over time, and brings extra latency.

Instead, you should provide your own implementation of IRandomAccessStream interface to the StartRecordToStreamAsync call. This way you’ll need no endless loops and no wait calls.

[Here’s some starting point.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13724901/126995)

The WriteAsync method will be called each time the OS has a portion of audio data for you. You can do whatever you want with the data.

If you aren’t saving the recording only doing that real-time analysis, you don’t even need the underlying Stream object. Just analyze the portion of the audio (don’t forget to skip wav header however), don't write it anywhere, and let it go.

If you need to save the recording, save it to the file, don’t keep audio data in RAM.