# UWP Media Playback with dynamic source

Tags: c#, uwp, media-player, media, uwp-xaml

i hope the title does not confuse you.

First: i am working with UWP c#.

I receive media-information (video and audio) in form of bytes from a remote device. Now i need to play them while new information is incoming.

For now, i have a FileStream, which writes the data everytime i receive the bytes. That works. But when i want to play this file, it just shows the media, that was written at the moment i call MediaElement.Play()
Is there any opportunity, the MediaElement (or another media player) keeps reading from the file or from the incomming bytes? Any Idea?

I'm afraid that this is not possible.

Comment: Do you mean you download the file that it does not finished, and you want to play it?

Comment: No, its no download. I receive the video data (currently in wmv format) over my custom network solution as byte arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `IRandomAccessStream` as wrapper for your `FileStream` and pass it to `MediaSource.CreateFromStream(IRandomAccessStream, string)` function.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13724901/3315714) is an example for implementing `IRandomAccessStream` on top of `MemoryStream`