# UWP C# : Progress of IAsyncOperationWithProgress

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, windows-runtime, winrt-async

How do I capture the progress of an `IAsyncOperationWithProgress` and send it to a `ProgressBar`?

```
var packageManager = new PackageManager();
var packageUri = new Uri("https://example.com/");
var options = AddPackageByAppInstallerOptions.None;
var defaultPackageVolume = packageManager.GetDefaultPackageVolume();

var operation = packageManager.AddPackageByAppInstallerFileAsync(packageUri, options, defaultPackageVolume);

operation.Progress( ??? ); // What should I do?
MyProgressBar.Value = ???; // I'd like to display installation progress % in real time.

await operation;
```

Comment: What part of the `IAsyncOperationWithProgress<TResult, TProgress>.Progress` property don't you understand? The documentation has examples, and there are other references on Stack Overflow, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112696/how-to-implement-iasyncoperationwithprogress) that provide useful information. In the code you posted, I would think that `operation.Progress = (asyncInfo, progressInfo) => MyProgressBar.Value = progressInfo.percentage;` would be appropriate, depending on how your `ProgressBar` is actually configured. Please improve the question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho much thanks! I've spent roughly an hour and couldn't find a working example of corresponding docs. I wouldn't have thought that the solution will be so simple. For some reason, I can't get it to work with a normal method and not a lambda.

Comment: A normal method declared properly will work just as well as a lambda. Of course, that "normal method" would need access to the `ProgressBar` instance, but it looks like you have it as an instance field, so that should be fine. Letting the `AsTask()` method mediate between the operation and your progress bar as in the posted answer below would probably work fine as well.

Comment: Could you provide an example how the handler method should look like? What parameters should it take, and which type return? Tried `void Handler(DeploymentResult result, DeploymentProgress progress)` with no luck. I totally don't understand this.

Comment: Your handler would need to be declared as `void Handler(IAsyncOperationWithProgress<DeploymentResult,DeploymentProgress> asyncInfo, DeploymentProgress progressInfo) { ... }`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.asyncoperationprogresshandler-2 for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to call `AsTask`:

```
var progress = new Progress<DeploymentProgress>(
    report => myProgressBar.Value = report.Percentage);
var operation = packageManager.AddPackageByAppInstallerFileAsync(packageUri, options, defaultPackageVolume)
    .AsTask(progress);

await operation;
```

Uncompiled and untested; some manipulation re `DeploymentProgress.Percentage` may be necessary.